I18n Modules not working with nuxt3 version 3.11.2
I followed the instructions for nuxt3 I18n Module.
I implemented the configuration  in the manner mentioned in Documention
2 - Results appear, but the words written inside the messages do not appear
Some pictures of the code results ...

This is the code ...

I tried adding some settings in nuxt.config.ts like
  build: {
    transpile: [/vue-i18n/],
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ar'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
      alwaysRedirect: true,
    },
    vueI18n: "ّّّ./i18n.config.ts",
  },

i18n.config.ts lock like
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      welcome: 'مرحباا',
    },
    ar: {
      welcome: 'مرحباا',
    },
  },
}))


What do you expect at $t? Do you have any errors in the console?

@kissu
No error appears on the console.
The result is in the picture above.
I wrote it to show that the $t function works

@BoussadjraBrahim
No, this is one of my attempts currently. I deleted it and put it in the question to avoid anyone telling me that this is one of the solutions.

I'd already struggled with i18n module and Nuxt, then this config worked for me :
  modules: [
      //other modules    
    "@nuxtjs/i18n"
  ],
 i18n: {
    locales: ["fr", "ar"],
    defaultLocale: "fr",
    vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
  },

i18n.config.ts
import fr from "./locales/fr-FR.json";
import ar from "./locales/ar-DZ.json";

export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  legacy: false,
  langDir: "./locales",
  locale: "fr",
  defaultLocale: "fr",
  messages: { fr, ar },
  baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
  locales: [
    {
      code: "fr",
      iso: "fr-FR",
    },
    {
      code: "ar",
      iso: "ar-DZ",
    },
  ],
}));

ar-DZ.json :
{
  "welcome": "مرحبا"
}



Thanks for the lengthy response
Unfortunately it did not solve my problem.
I still get this error
"[intlify] Not found 'welcome' key in 'fr' locale messages."

@mohammedalbadry he used an example with fr, but you probably have English or Arabic instead.

@kissu
No, I created a completely new project for testing and copied the attached code completely without modification

@mohammedalbadry the error is still obviously a key or locale file missing given the error.

In your new test code you need to create the fr-FR.json file or rename it to en-EN.json and put {"welcome":"whatever greeting you want goes here."} then change all cases of fr to en including code fr to code en and iso fr-FR to iso en-EN

I think this error is the problem with version compatibility

It is written in the special documentation nuxt/i18n
You are reading the v8 documentation compatible with Nuxt 3.
No exception was mentioned for version “3.11.2”.
